# Plotting circular 3d bars (discs) using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I am trying to make a graphical visualization of [reaction barriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_energy) in a cyclic reaction (cf. [citric acid cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid_cycle)).

I have barriers for two reaction paths closing the same reaction cycle through different
paths. A simple 2D plot becomes non-intuitive for this use case so I gave matplotlib's Axes3D object a shot:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import (absolute_import, division,
                        print_function, unicode_literals)

from math import sin, cos

import numpy as np

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm


def z_cycle(mesh, origin, cycle, r, angle_offset, ring_width=0.5):
    disc_radius = r/(len(cycle)+1)
    angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, len(cycle), endpoint=False)+angle_offset
    mesh_x, mesh_y = mesh
    xo, yo = origin
    z = np.zeros_like(mesh_x)
    for a, d in zip(angles, cycle):
        xc, yc = xo + r/2*cos(a), yo + r/2*sin(a)
        z += d*((mesh_x-xc)**2 + (mesh_y-yc)**2 < (0.2*r)**2)
    z0_mask = np.where(z == 0)
    ring = np.logical_and(
        (mesh_x-xo)**2+(mesh_y-yo)**2 < (r/2+ring_width/2*disc_radius)**2,
        (mesh_x-xo)**2+(mesh_y-yo)**2 > (r/2-ring_width/2*disc_radius)**2
    )
    z += min(cycle)/2*ring*(z == 0)
    return z


def main(data='1,3,2,4,3,4,2;1,3,1.5,2', r=1.0):
    """
    Plot energy barriers for reaction cycles in 3d

    Cycles as separated by semicolon, and individual
    barrier heights are separated by comma. Cycles need
    to share the value of their respective first barrier height.
    """

    max_barrier = None
    cycles = []
    max_ = lambda a, b: max(a, b) if b is not None else a
    for cycle_string in data.split(';'):
        cycle = []
        for barrier in map(float, cycle_string.split(',')):
            max_barrier = max_(barrier, max_barrier)
            cycle.append(barrier)
        cycles.append(cycle)

    assert all(cycle[0] == cycles[0][0] for cycle in cycles[1:])

    grid1d = np.linspace(-2*r, 2*r, 200)
    mesh_x, mesh_y = mesh = np.meshgrid(grid1d, grid1d)
    mesh_z = np.zeros_like(mesh_x)

    angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, len(cycles), endpoint=False)
    for angle, cycle in zip(angles, cycles):
        # cycle is an iterable of numerical values corresponding to
        # barrier heights
        disc_radius = r/(len(cycle)+1)
        centre = ((r/2+disc_radius)*cos(angle), (r/2+disc_radius)*sin(angle))
        mesh_z += z_cycle(mesh, centre, cycle, r, np.pi+angle)

    # Plot
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(mesh_x, mesh_y, mesh_z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                    cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidths=0)

    plt.savefig('barriers3d.png')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which gives me:

[image: cyclic circular 3dbar plot]

Problems with this method includes:

- Poor performance due to need of a very dense grid (rotating becomes sloooow)
- Graphical artefacts

Does anyone know a nice solution around these problems?

I tried to manually generate surfaces using `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection` but it is only sparsely documented.